# After libsvm installation, import svmutil is giving error - Python

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I am trying to use svmutil package. I installed libsvm from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libsvm. I installed the whl supported by my system.

c:\development\python 3.5.2\Scripts>pip install libsvm-3.22-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\development\python 3.5.2\scripts\libsvm-3.22-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: libsvm
Successfully installed libsvm-3.22

After this, I am getting the following error. Please help. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Check the `install_requires` on libsvm's setup.py. See if everything is installed in your site-packages. If there is a URL in it, setup tools could miss it. You may have to install it manually

Comment: Maybe there's a conflicting file `svm.py` in `sys.path`? What's the output of `import svm;print(svm.__file__)` in your script?

Comment: The output is c:\development\python 3.5.2\lib\site-packages\svm\__init__.py @cgohlke How to resolve that?

Comment: How to check that @RamkishoreM

Comment: `site-packages\svm\_init_.py` is the wrong package/file. Try uninstalling it: `python.exe -m pip uninstall svm`.